# Autofac Named Instance - Define Default Instance if Not Found

Tags: c#, autofac, named-instance

I'm using Autofac to register named instances.  I have to translate xml transactions into objects.

First, I have an enum.

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    [XmlNode("MyNodeA")]
    TypeA = 1,
    [XmlNode("MyNodeA")]
    TypeB = 2
}
```

I have a method that creates an `IDictionary<string, TransactionType>` using the `XmlNode` attribute on the enum.

Here is my autofac mapping

```
var mappings = TransactionTypeHelper.GetDictionary();

foreach (var mapping in mappings)
{
    builder.Register(ctx => {
                return mapping.Key;
    })
    .Named<TransactionType>(mapping.Value)
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

Then, I have a `TransactionTypeFactory` for getting the `TransactionType` based on the xml node.

```
public TransactionType GetTransactionType(string rootNode)
{
    return _container.Resolve<TransactionType>(rootNode?.ToLower());
}
```

My problem is that I want to pass through any unknown xml nodes as unknown transactions so that I can process new transactions without making any code changes.  The problem is that `_container.Resolve` throws an error if the node passed in has not been registered.

What I want to do is make autofac return the enum default if the named instance is not found instead of throwing an error.  The funny thing is, I have unit tests where this container is mocked, and they all pass, but Autofac specifically blows up on this call.

Comment: I suppose `ResolveOptionalNamed` should work here.

Comment: `ResolveOptionalNamed<T>` requires that `T` inherits from `class`.  I cannot use an enum.

Comment: You can create your own extension which will work with structs too. If that is fine for you I can show how exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is rather old, but I'd like to share a solution I have learned in the meantime in the hopes it will help someone with the same issue.

With autofac, you can register a function that can resolve using logic.

First, you would register each named instance.  In the question I was doing this with a helper and iterating through a collection, but the essence is to map each value of the enum to an instance.

```
builder.Register<TransactionAClass>(ctx =>
{
    //get any instances required by ConcreteClass from the ctx here and pass into the constructor
    return new TransactionAClass();
})
.Named<Interfaces.ITransactionInterface>($"{TransactionType.TypeA:f}")
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Once you have all your registrations for known values, then we register a resolver function.

```
builder.Register<Func<TransactionType, Interfaces.ITransactionInterface>>(ctx =>
{
    //you must resolve the context this way before being able to resolve other types
    var context = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();

    //get the registered named instance
    return (type) =>
    { 
        var concrete = context.ResolveNamed<Interfaces.ITransactionInterface>($"{type:f}");

        if (concrete == null)
        {
            //return a default class or throw an exception if a valid registration is not found
            return new TransactionAClass();
        }

        return concrete;
    }
});
```

Then, you can use the resolver like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ITransactionInterface transaction;

    public MyClass(Func<TransactionType, Interfaces.ITransactionInterface> transactionResolver)
    {
        transaction = transactionResolver.Invoke(TransactionType.TypeA);
    }
}
```